# Extend the given class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a javascript exercise working with objects and classes, I'm not very good with this and I don't know if I did it right, did I do it right?

1-
Extend the given class so that it implements a count() function that prints to the console the number of elements contained in the "value" property (do not modify the given constructor)

instantiate the class and call the new function count()

//Do not modify this constructor.

```
function Clase(elem){
  this.valor = [];
  this.valor['elem1'] = 1;
  this.valor['elem2'] = 2;
  this.valor['elem3'] = 3;
  this.valor['elem4'] = elem;
}
```

my code =>

```
function Clase(elem){
  this.valor = [];
  this.valor['elem1'] = 1;
  this.valor['elem2'] = 2;
  this.valor['elem3'] = 3;
  this.valor['elem4'] = elem;
}

class Extendida extends Clase{
  contar(){
    const keys = Object.keys(this.valor)
    console.log(Object.keys(this.valor))
    const keyslen = keys.length
    return keyslen
  }
}

const objeto = new Extendida(4)
objeto.contar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code's `contar()` method correctly returns the number of properties in `clase.valor`. `clase.valor` is an `Array` that is getting dynamic properties. Dynamic properties are not the same as `Array` elements, however.

For example:

```
let a = [];
a['x'] = 10;
console.log(a.length); // 0
console.log(Object.keys(a)); // ['x']
console.log(Object.keys(a).length); // 1
```

But if you could change `Clase` constructor, you could use `class` keyword for the base class. Also, instead of using an `Array` for `clase.valor`, you could use a `Map`:

```
class Clase {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.valor = new Map([
            ['elem1', 1],
            ['elem2', 2],
            ['elem3', 3],
            ['elem4', elem],
        ]);
    }

    // abstract
    contar() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then `Extendida`:

```
class Extendida extends Clase {
    // override
    contar() {
        const keys = Array.from(this.valor.keys())
        console.log(keys)
        const keyslen = this.valor.size
        return keyslen
    }
}
```

So, in real code sometimes you use either plain objects (or records), `Array`, `Map`, `Set` etc., but `Array` with dynamic properties is a confusing programming pattern.

Comment: I could use it too but I can't modify function Class(elem)